Question about Interest rate model and zero coupon bond
I am reading Technical Note No.31 of John Hull's book "Options, Furutes, and Other Derivatives". At the beginning, the PDE of a zero-coupon bond price is given by
\begin{equation}
dP(t,T)=rP(t,T)dt+v(t,T)P(t,T)dz
\end{equation}
where $r$ is the short rate, $v(t,T)$ is the volatolity. Then it says that: from Ito's lemma for any $T_1$ and $T_2$ with $T_2>T_1$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
d\ln P(t,T_1)= \left[r - \frac{v(t,T_1)^2}{2}\right] dt + v(t,T_1)dz(t)\\
d\ln P(t,T_2)= \left[r - \frac{v(t,T_2)^2}{2}\right] dt + v(t,T_2)dz(t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
However, according to Ito's lemma,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
d\ln P(t,T) &= \left[\frac{\partial\ln P}{\partial t} + rP\frac{\partial\ln P}{\partial P}  + \frac{1}{2}(vP)^2 \frac{\partial^2\ln P}{\partial P^2}\right] dt + vP\frac{\partial\ln P}{\partial P} dz(t)\\
& = \left[\frac{\partial\ln P}{\partial t} + r  - \frac{1}{2}v^2 \right] dt + v dz(t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
My question is why there is no term $\frac{\partial\ln P}{\partial t}$ in John Hull's technical note?

I think you are getting confused by the notation, as this is just an application of the univariate Ito's lemma. Write out the formula for $dX$ where $X=f(P)$ for some generic (suitably differentiable) $f$, and then substitute $f=\ln$.

Applying Ito's lemma to $\ln P(t,T)$:
\begin{aligned}
d\ln P(t,T) &= \frac{\partial\ln P(t,T)}{\partial P(t,T)} dP(t,T) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2\ln P(t,T)}{\partial P(t,T)^2} (dP(t,T))^2 \\
&= \frac{dP(t,T)}{P(t,T)} - \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{dP(t,T)}{P(t,T)} \right)^2 \\
&= \left( r dt+v(t,T) dz(t) \right) - \frac{1}{2} \left( v^2 dt \right) \\
&= \left( r - \frac{1}{2} v(t,T)^2 \right) dt + v(t,T) dz(t)
\end{aligned}
Notice that $\ln P(t,T)$ needs to be read as the function $\ln$ applied to $P(t,T)$. Therefore, the differentiation is with respect to $P(t,T)$.
